# MacBook Pro won´t let me log in after PRAM

Tags: macbook-pro, password, login, macos, nvram

I was having a problem with a pointer so after installing latest system updates with no effect on crazy pointer, I did a PRAM reset.

From then on, a log in page has changed:

1. my user name has changed (in past i was using my whole name as login name. Some months ago, I changed it for a 'nickname'. But now, after PRAM reset, the old/previous user account name appears.
2. there was another account 'guest' not secured by password. Now the password is required.
3. 'my account' with changed user name doesn't accept my valid password. When typing a password incorrectly for 3 times, there is pop-up to log in with my apple ID. That does not work either. The password is correct.

I am using this:

- MacBook Pro 2011 late
- latest operating system with updates
- I never changed my apple ID since created
- changed my Apple ID last year
- changed my computer password also about a year ago

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the main issue to address here is being able to log in again with a valid password. Once you've done that the rest can be sorted.

Since you've got a late 2011 MacBook Pro, you *should* be able to use these steps to reset your password from Recovery Mode:

1. Power off your MacBook Pro
2. Boot into Recovery Mode by pressing the power button while holding down <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>
3. If prompted, select your language and press <kbd>enter</kbd>
4. Choose Utilities > Terminal.
5. Enter `resetpassword` (all one word, lowercase letters)
6. Press <kbd>Return</kbd>
7. Select the drive with your account (typically the main drive)
8. Choose your account using Select the User Account.
9. Enter a new password
10. Re-enter the same password
11. Enter a password hint
12. Click Save
13. Ignore the warning about the password changing
14. Click OK.
15. Shutdown the Mac using Apple > Shut Down
16. Restart your MacBook Pro normally and use the new password to log into your account

Let me know if this doesn't work.